# What ROS and ROS2 releases goes with Ignition releases

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was unable to find any information on compatibility of Ignition Gazebo with the different versions of ROS and ROS 2. I can see for example the Ignition Citadel runs on both Ubuntu Focal and Bionic. Is it then safe to assume ether of the ROS Melodic and Noetic and ROS2 Dashing and Foxy would work with it? What combination is intended?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24804/what-ros-and-ros2-releases-goes-with-ignition-releases/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The branches being maintained on `ros_ign` can be compiled against multiple Ignition versions.

Right now, these are the versions being tested on CI for each branch:

`melodic` branch:

- ROS

  - Melodic
- Ignition

  - Blueprint
  - Citadel

`dashing` branch

- ROS

  - Dashing
- Ignition

  - Blueprint
  - Citadel

---

We're planning to add support for Noetic and Foxy shortly after they're released.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1